# Insurance required while renting a car in Iceland

Tags: driving, automobiles, iceland, reykjavik

I'm planning to rent a SUV from Reykjavik cars from Iceland but am confused with many options for insurance.

What are the insurance policies I do need to take to avoid any major issues?

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't just contact the rental companies _or_ your own insurance company and see what they/it says?

Comment: Thanks Campbell. But as a visitor, wondering what is essential and what is not?

Comment: Depends where you're planning to drive and how far, it's a question of risk after all. I'd argue it's a good idea to take the windshield insurance

Comment: Thanks blackbird. Based your knowledge, I believe, you had been to Iceland few times.